# How to download a .php website page using C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping

## Problem

I am trying to scrape a dynamic .php web page in C#. Whenever I call `GetStringAsync` on a known-good URL, it returns a 404 error.

#### Code Sample

```
public async Task<string> GetHtml()
{
    Uri phpUri = new("https://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php")
    HttpClient client = new();
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(phpUri); // Error here
    return response;
}
```

`phpUri` is the uri I can navigate to **in the browser** but not in code.

#### Possible Issues

I'm not super familiar with all the web tools provided in the .NET library, but perhaps there's a different library/class (not `HtmlClient`) that works better with dynamic pages? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Often this kind of issue comes down to a server expecting a User-Agent header, which API clients often don't provide by default. `HttpClient` certainly doesn't. Try setting that.

Comment: When I open the given resource in my browser, I also get a 404 in the netwerk tools, but the page loads normally. Maybe the problem is server side. Do you try tools like Postman?

Comment: try using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method here is he link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

Reposting DiplomacyNotWar's comment here as an answer: I had to set the User-Agent header. Here's how I modified the code

```
public async Task<string> GetHtml()
{
    Uri phpUri = new("https://nflcombineresults.com/nflcombinedata.php")
    HttpClient client = new();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Get, UrlDataSource);
    ProductInfoHeaderValue productValue = new("ScraperBot", "1.0");

    // Add the User-Agent header
    request.Headers.UserAgent.Add(productValue);

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}
```